# what is the significance of schema name in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server. I connected to SQL server via SQuirrel Client.

Connection URL:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://192.xx.xx.xx:1433;databaseName=ep
```

with **username** & **password**.

Then I tried a query on `table1` in `schema1` -

```
SELECT * from table1
```

It returned records. I did not mention schema name in query.

There may be possibility of having tables in different sachems (*same database*) **with same name**.

Am I right? If yes, then how will it resolve schema name?

Comment: When no schema mentioned, it will select from the current logged in schema. If you want a table from another schema with the same name, you will have to mention the schema name like SCHEMA.table1

Comment: @sagi how will it decide **current logged in schema** as I have not mentioned in connection URL?

Comment: @dev, by default it takes "dbo." schema as default schema

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095(v=sql.100).aspx

please read it. hope this will clear the point you wanted to ask..

Comment: What he said:) And you can alter it inside your DBMS tool

Comment: @RamSingh that cleared my confusion. Thanks...:)

Comment: The best practice is to always schema-qualify objects unless you have a reason not to (besides laziness).  This practice avoids ambiguity and improves performance of query compilation and reuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema work like a namespace in SQL SERVER, you can create tables, views, sps under a schema and set GRANT, DENY, or REVOKE permissions on those objects. From [Implementation of Database Object Schemas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095(v=sql.100).aspx)

> SQL Server 2005 implemented the concept of a database object schema. A schema is a distinct namespace to facilitate the separation, management, and ownership of database objects. It removed the tight coupling of database objects and owners to improve the security administration of database objects. Database object schemas offer functionality to control and help secure application objects within a database environment not available in previous versions of SQL Server.

Just wanted to add here, if you have not specified any schema than, it select **dbo** as schema.

Answer (score -1):

It is distinguished by its owner. Every object (table ,view ,proc) has an owner which must be a user in the database. For example you may have user1.table1 and user2.table2 in the same database.

So you may type

```
select * from user1.table1
```

and

```
select * from user2.table1
```

You may see names like dbo.table_name, this means that the owner is the dbo, the database owner. If you do not specify an owner then the system checks dbo and your user (the user that run the command)

Comment: "Every object (table ,view ,proc) has an owner which must be a user in the database. For example you may have user1.table1 and user2.table2 in the same database." - **this is untrue**, and hasn't been the case since SQL Server 2005, [as the other answer elucidates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35552775/159145). Schema names have been entirely independent of ownership for the past 17 years now.